# Body element has no margin but children's margin affects body's margin

Tags: css, reactjs

1. body has margin: 0
2. p tags has margin-top: 100px;

p tags affects body's margin-top why?

I expected margin-top:100px only affects p tags.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I wonder why should I use padding-top instead of margin-top?

> Margins create extra space around an element. In contrast, padding creates extra space within an element.

In this case p tags are located in body so margin and padding should be looks same

[image]
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lktg4q?file=style.css

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

h1, p {
  font-family: Lato;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top:100px;
}

#root {
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
      </div>
```

Comment: As you can see, You have applied margin-top for both `h1` and `p`

Comment: Replace `margin-top` with `padding-top` if all you want is the top part to remain blue

Comment: As per my understanding you need blue color throught body. For that you need to apply `padding-top`

Comment: This is an effect the H1 margin-top you can replace margin-top to padding-top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the effect of [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing#See_also). According to that MDN page:

> **Parent and first/last child**
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline part, block formatting context created, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block; or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

There are many ways to go about trying to work around it. But understanding this concept is one step to doing it.

In your case, the margin of the first element in your body (which is `h1`) affects the margin of the body. If you wish to not have a margin on the first `h1`, you could add this ([see it on this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxewu59o/)):

```
h1:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

This assume your first element in the body is an `h1`.

Comment: Some additional reading: https://bitsofco.de/collapsible-margins/

Answer (score 0):

Apply `padding-top` instead of `margin-top`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

h1,
p {
  font-family: Lato;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

#root {
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div>
    <h1>Hello React!</h1>
    <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have updated your code.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tbw7x4?file=style.css)

Comment: What if the OP want's `margin-top:100px` for `h1` also?

Comment: I wonder why should I use padding-top instead of margin-top?

Comment: You should add more to this answer instead of a single URL. If the StackBlitz example got deleted, this answer would become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this,

```
#root {
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

I can say that you want background color to your body, as `#root` is the parent element and no element can be made parent to this, you can add `#root` `css` to your `html, body` `css`,

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}

h1, p {
  font-family: Lato;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top:100px;
}
```

Now coming to the scroll on the page, the scroll is coming because of `margin-top:100px`. You can fix this in two ways.

**1st Way,**

If `margin-top:100px` is the fixed layout throughout your application then,

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: calc(100vh-100px); //minus your margin from viewport height will eliminate scroll
  background: blue;
}
```

**2nd way,**

Replace `margin-top` with `padding-top`, because padding is included in element height and margin not.

```
h1, p {
  font-family: Lato;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top:100px;
}
```